# Replace only text contents of html element with jQuery, preserving font awesome i tags

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

Here is the test case:
`<span id='loading' class="pad"> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Loading map... </span>`

I am trying to dynamically ( via jQuery ) , change *only* the "Loading map..." portion of this markup.  I realize I can rebuild the whole inner contents every time , incorporating and replacing `<i .... {new message here} ... </i>` but I am curious to know if there is a supported api method for this.

I thought *$('#loading').text('new message')* would work but it removes the `<i>` tag.

Comment: Is it possible for you to wrap the changeable part into another tag? Then, it could be so easy

Comment: @Mojtaba - sure as long as the visual output doesn't change. Thanks 4 ?

Comment: try `$('#loading').html($('#loading i')[0].outerHTML +'new message')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use get the object of text node and set the content using textContent:

```
$('#loading').contents().last()[0].textContent='new message';
```

```js
$('#loading').contents().last()[0].textContent='new message';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='loading' class="pad"> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Loading map... </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function changeText(newText){
curI = $('#loading > i')[0].outerHTML;
$('#loading').html(curI + newText);
}

changeText('Hey. I am the new text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='loading' class="pad"> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Loading map... </span>
```

By the way, if you could wrap the changeable text inside another tag, then, you could directly change it regardless the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, like:

```
$('#loading').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('Loading map...','new message');
});
```

**Simple Demo:**

```js
$('#loading').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('Loading map...','new message here...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<span id='loading' class="pad"> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Loading map... </span>
```

If you check the browser console you will find `<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-lg fa-fw"></i>` element is still there, it just not shown here as font-awesome is not included here. (*Edit: Added the fa css also.*)

Comment: @palasH what does the 3 represent ?

Comment: It represent a `TEXT_NODE` which is the actual text of element. More details [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is replace all text that isn't wrapped within any child element, the most general approach I can see is setting the content of the element to it's child elements (omitting the text-only content), then appending the desired text, like this:

```js
$('#loading').html($('#loading').children()).append('new message');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='loading' class="pad">
  <div>static element of any kind</div>
  text to replace
</span>
```

---

However, the most straightforward way would be to define an element from the start, then set a new content for that.

```js
$('#message').text('new message');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='loading' class="pad">
  <div>static element of any kind</div>
  <div id="message">text to replace</div>
</span>
```